# Execute parameterized stored procedure after an activity in DataFlow Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

Below is the data table result after an activity in DataFlow Azure Data Factory, after this step there should be a stored procedure call where it will take `Description` as input, which is comma separated and the output will be one of them:

Input is

```
"DEED,InDeed,Excal"
```

Assume the output may be one of them "InDeed"

[image]

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBo0.png)

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: I want to call a stored procedure after a derived column in the DataFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Call the stored procedure activity in your pipeline after data flow activity.

1. In your data flow store the derived column data in blob storage or in any dummy table in SQL database using sink transformation.
2. In the pipeline, connect your data flow activity to a lookup activity, to pull the data which is stored in the sink (step 1).
3. Add stored procedure activity after lookup activity and pass the output values from lookup as Input parameters to stored procedure activity.

Comment: I want to update a column of a dataset with the Output of the stored procedure.

Comment: Fixed this at the back end in a stored procedure, and simply called the respective stored procedure in the pipeline.